# Cannot autologin on Ubuntu 14.04 after updates

Tags: 14.04, boot, login, lightdm, auto-login

I just do some updates and now I cannot autologin into my Ubuntu 14.04. Previously, I can autologin, sometimes I cannot. I guess, this is caused by something with systemd. Here my auth.log when booting,

```
Jul 31 06:05:02 bagustris-MacBookPro lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user bagustris by (uid=0)
Jul 31 06:05:02 bagustris-MacBookPro systemd-logind[1138]: New session c1 of user bagustris.
Jul 31 06:05:02 bagustris-MacBookPro systemd-logind[1138]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/1000/X11-display.
Jul 31 06:05:03 bagustris-MacBookPro gnome-keyring-daemon[1759]: couldn't set environment variable in session: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Jul 31 06:05:03 bagustris-MacBookPro gnome-keyring-daemon[1759]: message repeated 2 times: [ couldn't set environment variable in session: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files]
Jul 31 06:05:05 bagustris-MacBookPro gnome-keyring-daemon[1759]: The GPG agent was already initialized
Jul 31 06:05:05 bagustris-MacBookPro gnome-keyring-daemon[1759]: The SSH agent was already initialized
Jul 31 06:05:05 bagustris-MacBookPro gnome-keyring-daemon[1759]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Jul 31 06:05:05 bagustris-MacBookPro gnome-keyring-daemon[1759]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Jul 31 06:05:07 bagustris-MacBookPro polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.40 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul 31 06:05:11 bagustris-MacBookPro dbus[979]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.20" (uid=0 pid=1816 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=1280 comm="NetworkManager ")
Jul 31 06:05:12 bagustris-MacBookPro polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.40, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul 31 06:05:12 bagustris-MacBookPro lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session closed for user bagustris
```

My PC is macbook pro 13", mid2012. I also added `autologin-user=myusername`
 in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf. Of course, I also set aulogin in System Settings >> User Account.

Any idea to solve this problem? I need autologin to fasten my booting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying, I got it works again. I don't know which solution worked, but I did the following:
In /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf I add:

```
  pam-autologin-service=lightdm-autologin
```

I create new file /etc/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf containing the following [as explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin):

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=bagustris
```

Another work around is to check /etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin. Make sure no strange or permission issue, and refer login setting found to this "ligthdm-autologin".

There is another work around as listed from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss-pam-ldapd/+bug/1314095) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/871667):

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/shadow
sudo chown user:user .Xauthority
```